# Android Room - best way to retrieve a record to be updated

Tags: android, android-room

I have an app which has a session end routine. I want to update the session with the end date/time and potentially other information when the End Session button is clicked. I have a dao, a repository, and a ViewModel.

I thought the best way to do this would be to get the record, update the fields in the object, and save the object back to Room.

I don't exactly know the best way to go about this. Here is the code I am working with:

In the Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Session WHERE id=:id")
Single<Session> getSessionById(int id);
```

In the repository:

```
public Single<Session> getSessionById(int sessionId) {
    return sessionDao.getSessionById(sessionId);
}
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public void endSession () {

    Single<Session> session = sessionRepository.getSessionById(sessionId);
    //????? session.doOnSuccess()

    //get current date/time
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    //set the end date
    session.setEndTime(date);

    //update the session
    sessionRepository.update(session);
}
```

I would love any advice on the range of options. I had started using a plain object, but got errors related to running the query on the main thread and wanted to avoid that. I don't need an observable/flowable object. I understand Async is to be deprecated in Android 11. So I thought Single would work.

Any advice on my choice to use Single or code would be really helpful.

UPDATE:
I just need a simple example in Java of pulling a single record from and the main part is the functionality in the ViewModel (what does the doOnSuccess look like and optionally on error as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to update without retrieving the whole record, writing a custom query is the option that I go with:

```
@Query("UPDATE table_name SET column_name = :value WHERE id = :id")
fun update(id: Int, value: String): Completable
```

In repository:

```
fun update(id: Int, value: String): Completable
```

In ViewModel or UseCase:

```
update().subscribeOn(...).observeOn(...).subscribe()
```

---

If you want to avoid using RxJava:

```
@Query("UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value WHERE id = :id")
fun update(id: Int, value: String): Boolean
```

And use [Executors](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor()) to run transactions on a background thread.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute { 
   repository.update()
}
```

---

If you want to perform both retrieving and updating you can use `@Update` and `@Query` to retrieve the recorded inside your ViewModel or UseCase (interactor) and push the update toward Room.

---

RxJava Single Example:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_name")
fun getAll(): Single<List<Model>>
```

Repository:

```
fun getAll(): Single<List<Model>> = modelDao.getAll()
```

ViewModel or UseCase:

```
val statusLiveData = MutableLive<Strig>()

modelRepository.getAll()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ statusLiveData.value = "Success" }, { statusLiveData.value = "Failed" })
```

Comment: I was thinking of the update as well, but I still needed to work on a single retrieve. I have seen a lot of examples where data is passed to a detail screen after the onclick of a recyclerview. I wanted to pass the ID to the detail screen and retrieve the record from there as there could be more extensive information.

Comment: Would use use a Single<Session> to retrieve a single record which could then be manipulated then updated or would you use something else?

Comment: I always go with Single<Model> when working with Retrofit/Room and Single only returns an error or a success (with data) which I think is the best option to go with.

Comment: Thanks, @abstract Arrow. Do you have some simple code to demonstrate the Single<Model> doOnSuccess call?

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Can you give me an example of what happens in the place where you have comments ("// onSuccess > update live data or any other stuff}, {// onError > handle error status}") just so I can see what that looks like?

Comment: @lcj Check the update I hope it clears it out for you

Comment: Does this look different in Java? Again, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @lcj no it doesn't. Look at some sample codes on Github. I believe StackOverFlow is not a good place to clear out all your questions about an Architecture.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am new to Android/Room and SO has been amazing places where I face challenges. There seem to be so many techniques out there that it is hard to determine if I am taking a sound approach or not. FYI, I used Executors.